# Is it bad to put the parallelization controller code in view model in MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, parallel-processing

I am writing a program using MVVM pattern. The program will execute a huge number of tasks in parallel and the result will be updated in the frontend GUI. I want the GUI to be updated when each task is finished and I am using barrier etc to control the task execution.

My question is where do I put the code containing the barrier, in viewmodel or model? It is easy to put it in the viewmodel code, but I don't think it complies with the MVVM pattern.

But if it is to put the code in model, does it mean I need to pass in the view model objects to the model in order for the object to be updated when the task completes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your model should be as clean and portable as possible. Even if you decide to put your processing logic in the model it certainly should not know anything about the layers above i.e your ViewModels. You can solve that by having events on the model (like Done, ProgressChanged etc.) that are capable of notifying the interested ViewModels.
On the matter of where should this processing logic reside i'd have to say it depends.
Is this processing a core part of your domain? Is this something that your domain will have to do again on other occasions? Should this code be reusable?
In that case it seems like it belongs to your model.

Having said that i believe this kind of logic belongs mainly inside the ViewModel layer. You can still use your model to possibly store the number or tasks or the results of the processing and so on but not the actual processing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the advise. I think this parallelisation logic should belong to the model and the view model can register its interests via events. I think viewmodel should be tightly bound to the view